# Бордер у псевдоэлемента отображается не корректно

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Должно быть так:

[image: Toolbar]

Получается так:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aside {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Quicksand";
  height: 450px;
}

.aside .wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1180px;
}

.aside .wrapper .toolbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid #e5e3e3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.aside .wrapper .toolbar h2 {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.aside .wrapper .toolbar span {
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aside .wrapper .aside__text {
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.aside__big-projects {
  width: 220px;
}

.aside__big-projects .toolbar h2 {
  color: #f34739;
}

.aside__big-projects .toolbar::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  border-left: 4px solid #f34739;
}

.aside__big-projects .toolbar::before {
  content: '';
}

.aside__clients {
  width: 220px;
}

.aside__clients .toolbar h2 {
  color: #009989;
}

.aside__months {
  width: 220px;
}

.aside__months .toolbar h2 {
  color: #152b3c;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="aside__big-projects">
      <div class="toolbar">
        <h2>50</h2>
        <span>Big Projects</span>
      </div>
      </span class="aside__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="aside__clients">
      <div class="toolbar">
        <h2>35</h2>
        <span>Clients</span>
      </div>
      </span class="aside__text">Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed incididunt!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="aside__months">
      <div class="toolbar">
        <h2>80</h2>
        <span>Months</span>
      </div>
      </span class="aside__text">Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 4px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f00;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код так, чтобы можно было запустить

Comment: https://codepen.io/kakabylik/pen/pZBdxw